What is the difference between a Lindbladian and a Liouvillian in open quantum systems?
As far as I know, when we try to write the Lindbladian equation in a generalized nice operator basis we get Liouvillian. Is this correct?
What are the differences between them?

This doesn't need any more details or clarity. Just ask it at MMSE and I'll answer it.

Liouvillian is a general term for the generator of a master equation. Every Lindbladian is a Liouvillian but not every Liouvillian has Lindblad form.
